# ImportError: cannot import name 'NDArray' from 'numpy.typing' (Prophet)

Tags: python, numpy, facebook-prophet

I have not had as much trouble trying to install any other package in my Python experience than I have with Prophet.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
#Import libraries
import pandas as pd
from prophet import Prophet

#Load data
test = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/prophet/main/examples/example_wp_log_peyton_manning.csv')
test.head()

# Train model
model = prophet()
model.fit(test)
```

I get the following error:

```
----> 4 from prophet import Prophet
      7 # Train model
      8 model = prophet()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/prophet39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prophet/__init__.py:7
      1 # Copyright (c) 2017-present, Facebook, Inc.
      2 # All rights reserved.
      3 #
      4 # This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
      5 # LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
      6 # of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
----> 7 from prophet.forecaster import Prophet
      9 from pathlib import Path
     10 about = {}

File ~/anaconda3/envs/prophet39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prophet/forecaster.py:17
     15 import numpy as np
     16 import pandas as pd
---> 17 from numpy.typing import NDArray
     19 from prophet.make_holidays import get_holiday_names, make_holidays_df
     20 from prophet.models import StanBackendEnum

ImportError: cannot import name 'NDArray' from 'numpy.typing' (/Users/user_name/anaconda3/envs/prophet39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/typing/__init__.py)
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem.  I've encountered several different `prophet/pystan` issues along the way, but seems like I've hit quite the roadblock this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try upgrading your `numpy` and `prophet` installations. It seems that updating [has resolved a similar issue in the past](https://github.com/meshpro/optimesh/discussions/90).

Comment: I upgraded numpy to 1.23.5 and prophet was already at 1.1.2 the most up to date version as of today.  Ran it again and I got an import error for prophet.

Comment: It worked - after updating numpy I caught a typo with a function! THANK YOU!